# Laravel API routes on subdomain are routing on web before they go to api routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, localhost, laragon

I'm trying to implement laravel api through a subdomain not a prefix. So, I'm working locally using laragon and I already have my project installed on example.test. Then I went to vhosts and added a record to relate api.example.test to 127.0.0.1 as the same domain.
Then I Added my RouteServiceProvider to update the api routes and make it use domain ('api.example.test') to redirect routes to my api.php file.

The problem is: All routes to api.example.test are firstly going through web routes then if didn't find any match it goes to api routes and try to match! So how can I fix this?

[My RouteServiceProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsYAl.png)

[api.php my API routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihBG4.png)

[web.php my Web routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daw60.png)

[The problem! the route checks web routes first before it checks in api!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhE4J.png)

[Now I change route in web routes. not the same routes anymore and i check postman again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kOtr.png)

[It works fine if not match in web routes!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNMf4.png)

any solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: Just copy/paste the code, don't paste the images. If somethings wrong in the code it's easier to copy text

Comment: Thanks. it's my second question here that's why I didn't know what to do. I'll keep this in mind next time !

Comment: @UnderDog I'm sorry but is there a way to mark this question as solved? or I can leave it like this? It's already solved and I've commented the solution.

Comment: It's easy and you did it right: answer your own question, then mark that answer as accepted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks. I found it but it says I only can do it in 2 days. If I remember I will xD

Answer (score 1):

Already solved! The problem was with my fortify configuration as I set it to have a prefix for localization `{locale}` and due to fortify routes aren't in routes web file I think it hooks them to service provider so API routes were going to fortify first.
Solved by setting `'domain' => 'example.test'` in fortify config file.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer till after 2 days.